# JNDI path Tomcat vs. Jboss

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jboss, jndi

I have DataSource which is configured on Tomcat 6 in context.xml as MyDataSource.
And I'm fetching it the following way:

```
      DataSource dataSource;
            try {
                dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/MyDataSource");
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                throw new DaoConfigurationException(
                    "DataSource '" + url + "' is missing in JNDI.", e);
            }
```

Everything works fine. Now I'm exporting this code to Jboss AP 6. and I configured my dataSource and its connection pool as local-tx dataSource under the same name.

When I'm executing the code above, I'm getting NamingException exception. after some investigation I've found that correct way to call my DataSource under Jboss is

```
 dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:/MyDataSource");
```

Can anybody explain me why should I omit "comp/env" in my JNDI path under Jboss?

Comment: Could you also add the entries for your `web.xml` and `jboss-web.xml`?

Comment: @CoolBeans, I don't have any more entries.

Comment: @denny.lesnik: Alright. Next question is do you have `<use-java-context>` parameter set to true in your data source xml (*-ds.xml)?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676/tomcat-vs-weblogic-jndi-lookup ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The portable approach for defining data sources is to use a ***resource reference***. Resource references enable you to define the JNDI name for your data source, relative to your application naming context (`java:comp/env`), and then map that *logical reference* to the *physical resource* defined in the application server, whose JNDI name is *proprietary* to the application server vendor. This approach enables your code and assembly to be portable to any compliant application server.

## Step 1: Declare and Lookup Resource Reference

### Option 1

This can be done by declaring a `resource-ref` in your web deployment descriptor (`WEB-INF/web.xml`):

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>My Data Source.</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyDataSource</res-ref-name> 
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Within your code, you can then lookup this resource using the JNDI name `java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDataSource`:

```
dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDataSource");
```

This JNDI name will not change regardless of the server where the application is deployed.

### Option 2

Alternatively, starting in Java EE 5 (Servlet 2.5), this can be done even easier within your code using the [`@Resource`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html) annotation. This eliminates the need for configuring the resource-ref in your web deployment descriptor (web.xml) and prevents the need to perform an explicit JNDI lookup:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Resource(name = "jdbc/MyDataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // dataSource may be accessed directly here since the container will automatically
        // inject an instance of the data source when the servlet is initialized

}
```

This approach has the same results as the previous option, but cuts down on the boilerplate code and configuration in your assembly.

## Step 2: Map Resource Reference to Data Source

Then, you will need to use your application server's proprietary approach for mapping the resource reference to the *physical data source* that you created on the server, for example, using JBoss's custom deployment descriptors (`WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyDataSource</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <jndi-name>java:/MyDataSource</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

Or, for example, using Tomcat's `context.xml`:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDataSource" . . . />
```

Comment: I think `<ResourceLink>` is a more appropriate alternative to `<resource-ref>`. `<Resource>` will just define a brand new resource, rather than referencing and renaming a global one.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your data source definition the 'jndi-name' tag:

> jndi-name - the JNDI name under which the DataSource should be bound.

You can find data source documentation on JBoss wiki: [ConfigDataSources](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigDataSources)