# What is the standard naming convention of JNDI Name for a Datasource?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, datasource, jndi, application-server

What is the standard naming convention of `JNDI Name` for a Datasource?

Suppose I have a Datasource named **MyAppDS**. What is the standard naming convention of `JNDI Name` for **MyAppDS**?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard naming convention, a common naming convention is "jdbc/MyAppDS". Its something you always manually configure, so you're free to pick what you want really. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/resource-creation002.htm#BNCJJ

Comment: See [this inter-linked answer for similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34496196/441652).

Answer (score 8):

[JNDI / Naming Policies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/misc/policy.html):

> The enterprise namespace is rooted in a URL context for the java URL
>   scheme. For example, you might use a name such as
>   "java:comp/env/ejb/Payroll" for Payroll ejb. At the root context of
>   the namespace is a binding with the name "comp", which is bound to a
>   subtree reserved for component-related bindings. The name "comp" is
>   short for component. In the "comp" context, there is binding for
>   "env".The name "env" is bound to a subtree that is reserved for the
>   component's environment-related bindings, as defined by its deployment
>   descriptor. "env" is short for environment. The J2EE recommends (but
>   does not require) the following structure for the "env" namespace.
>
> Resource factory references are placed in subtrees differentiated by
>   their resource manager type. Here are some examples:
>
> ```
> "jdbc" for JDBCTM DataSource references
> "jms" for JMS connection factories
> "mail" for JavaMail connection factories
> "url" for URL connection factories
> ```
>
> For example, a JDBC Salary database might have the name
>   "java:comp/env/jdbc/Salary".

Answer (score 0):

A resource is a program object that provides connections to systems, such as database 
servers and messaging systems. (A Java Database Connectivity resource is sometimes 
referred to as a data source.) Each resource object is identified by a unique, 
people-friendly name, called the JNDI name. For example, the JNDI name of the
preconfigured JDBC resource for the Java DB database that is shipped with the 
GlassFish Server is java:comp/DefaultDataSource. (Java EE official tutorial :Part III Chapter 3.1)

Three JNDI namespaces are used for portable JNDI lookups: java:global, 
java:module, and java:app. (Java EE official tutorial :Part VII Chapter 32.4.1.1)

By example here is the way Netbeans will call your DB connection in ressource configuration file : jndi-name="jdbc/UrDataSourceName" and the complete jndi name will probably be "java:jdbc/UrDataSourceName"