# Bean Lookup Error

Tags: java, jboss, tomcat6

The following code works fine in JBoss, but when deployed in Apache Tomcat it gives

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [SPConnectorClient] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [SPConnectorClient].

Code:

```
logger.info("SPConnectorClientEJB::callSubmitRequest");
        SPResponse response = new SPResponse();
        Object responseObj = null;
        try
        {
          InitialContext ctx = null;

          ctx = new InitialContext();
          logger.info("Got InitialContext");

          SPConnectorClientHome home = (SPConnectorClientHome)ctx.lookup("SPConnectorClient");

          SPConnectorClientRemote remote = null;
          remote = home.create();
          logger.info("Got Remote Object!");
```

Code in Setenv.sh file:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DSPAppspecificJNDI=java:global/SP/sp_app_specific/SPConnectorClient!com.cdac.sp.SPConnectorClientRemote"
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are missing a JAR file which JBoss has but Tomcat does not?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224216/jndi-path-tomcat-vs-jboss)