# I am Moving my application Web-logic to Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, migration, weblogic

The below code is working fine while the application is running in weblogic but in tomcat it is giving an error. 
The main problem is loading `java:comp/env/jmx/runtime`.

**So please let me know what configuration I need to do to run the code in tomcat.**

My Code:

```
    MBeanServer server = (MBeanServer)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jmx/runtime");
    // Get the Platform MBean Server
    ObjectName rs = new ObjectName("com.bea:Name=RuntimeService,Type=weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime.RuntimeServiceMBean");
    HashMap map = null;
    try
    {
        ObjectName domCfg = (ObjectName) server.getAttribute(rs,"DomainConfiguration");

        ObjectName[] jdbcSysResources =
        (ObjectName[]) server.getAttribute(domCfg, "JDBCSystemResources");

        map = new HashMap();
        for (int i=0 ; i<jdbcSysResources.length ; i++)
        {
            ObjectName jdbcResourceBean = (ObjectName) server.getAttribute(jdbcSysResources[i],"JDBCResource");

            ObjectName driverParamsBean =(ObjectName)server.getAttribute(jdbcResourceBean,"JDBCDriverParams");
            StringBuffer jdbcParams = new StringBuffer();
            ObjectName drvPropertiesBean = (ObjectName)server.getAttribute(driverParamsBean,"Properties");
            ObjectName[] drvProperties = (ObjectName[])server.getAttribute(drvPropertiesBean,"Properties");

            for(int j=0; j<drvProperties.length; j++)
            {
                String propName = (String)server.getAttribute(drvProperties[j],"Name");
                String propVal = (String)server.getAttribute(drvProperties[j],"Value");
                jdbcParams.append(propName).append("=").append(propVal).append(";");
            }
            String strTest = drvProperties.toString();

            ObjectName dsnParams =(ObjectName)server.getAttribute(jdbcResourceBean,"JDBCDataSourceParams"); 
            String[] dsnParamNames = (String[])server.getAttribute(dsnParams,"JNDINames");
            map.put(dsnParamNames[0].toString(),jdbcParams.toString());
```

Error in tomcat server:-

```
SystemCheck - Naming Exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: 
Name [jmx/runtime] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jmx].
04/22 01:32 SystemAvailability -> MEL check failed - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Tomcat Context.xml---
 -- Data source 1 --
       < Resource name="jdbc/datasource1" auth="Container"      driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" maxActive="50" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000"  password="mel01" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx:1460;databaseName=xxx" username="xxx" validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>
  -- Data source 2 --
.
..

```
    < Resource  name="jdbc/datasource2"  auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" maxActive="50" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000"password="xxxx" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx:1460;databaseName=xxx" username="xxx" validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>
```

Web.xml---

```
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/datasouce1</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>CONTAINER</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/datasouce2</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>CONTAINER</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676/tomcat-vs-weblogic-jndi-lookup

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat doesn't come with a JNDI broker, unlike Weblogic. To make the code work as is, you'd need to add some JNDI provider.

I'd recommend using DI instead.

spring framework can do either (for example).

[Here's an example](http://www.journaldev.com/2597/spring-datasource-jndi-with-tomcat-example)

Comment: It is a legacy application. I cant use DI/Spring here. So please let me know how can I lookup all JNDI in tomcat.