# Impossible to deploy on Weblogic

Tags: java, maven

I tried to apply all the solutions in these questions:

[Tomcat vs Weblogic JNDI Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676/tomcat-vs-weblogic-jndi-lookup)

[javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:while trying to lookup jdbc](http://javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:while%20trying%20to%20lookup%20jdbc)

but they didn't solve my problem.
I'm using Maven and WebLogic.

In my web.xml I used the tag 'res-ref-name'.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How come you edited the question? Now none of the answers make any sense

Answer (score 1):

You have registered your data source withh the name "**jndi**/ConsipGfrDS", but looking up with "**jdbc**/ConsipGfrDS". Use one (no matter what, but the same) name in both cases.

I'd suggest that you use in JNDI the name "**jdbc**/ConsipGfrDS", because it will be easier to sort objects out if you have many objects in JNDI.

Answer (score 1):

This is old fashioned JNDI and you have a couple of problems here.

Your `web.xml` has correctly defined

```
<res-ref-name>jdbc/ConsipGfrDS</res-ref-name>
```

These resource references define names in the JNDI `java:comp/env` namespace, otherwise known as the component environment namespace which is local to your web application. This means that the full JNDI name of your datasource in your web application is actually `java:comp/env/jdbc/ConsipGfrDS`, so your lookup code should be:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    return (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/ConsipGfrDS");
}
```

So far we have platform *independent* (i.e. application server) code. You have correctly pushed the platform *dependent* part into the `weblogic.xml` file.

However this is where your second problem lies. The `weblogic.xml` contains a small error. The weblogic console image that you provided showing the JDBC DataSource configuration says that the JNDI name is `jdbc/ConsipGfrDS`. Therefore, update it as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<weblogic-web-app
    xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://http://www.oracle.com/technology/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.1/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <resource-description>
        <!-- match jndi name in weblogic -->
        <jndi-name>jdbc/ConsipGfrDS</jndi-name>
        <!-- match res-ref-name name in web.xml -->
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/ConsipGfrDS</res-ref-name>
    </resource-description>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

Have fun!

Comment: You changed the java code as I suggested? Do you have the same error message - or has it changed?